# Can you tell me the difference between 'all over the world' and 'throughout the world'?

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me the difference between these phrases: **'all over the world'** and **'throughout the world'** as well as give me some examples?

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing.

As a British person, there's a very slight difference in what the phrases make me visualise but it's subjective. And it only really matters for descriptive language, because the two phrases have the exact same definition. Just think about other times you would use 'all over' and other times you would use 'throughout' and how that affects the mental image for the reader.

Comment: While their message is the same, you might prefer one or the other in a certain context. For example, I would say; **Her songs were sung all over the world.** and **The virus spread throughout the world.** This choice is not correct or wrong, it's merely personal. It's what sounds best to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hope you have a nice day!